# Finding if a web page needs to be crawled or a POST request must be sent

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, web-crawler, http-post

How to i find out if i need to crawl the pages source or i can substitute it with a POST request and save myself the trouble? I am using `python 3.5`. Pages i need are:

https://www.fathom.org/experience-whats-included/#spot

http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results[enter link description here](http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results)

https://www.pocruises.com.au/cruises/search#?sort=dpa&page=1

I am very bad with frontend stuff and i can't seem to find how these things are done.
Thanks in advance
EDIT: sending post request to `http://www.pocruises.com/find-and-book/cruise-search-results/` returns `<Response [200]>`. Does that mean i cannot send a request and i have to scrape the whole page?

Comment: `"How to i find out if i need to crawl the pages source"` do you mean by if they are populated/loaded? If not I don't know how you would "need" to crawl it or not....

Comment: yes if they are populated. In all three cases i need the cruises info

Comment: You could send a HEAD request in to see if the page is valid, but if it needs some user clicks to get information off that page (ie javascript loads) then you will need a phantom scrapper or selenium

Comment: those words mean nothing to me man :) can you simplify

Comment: Basically, how websites are made are either static loads (meaning the information is all there on the site) or dynamically load (meaning the information is only on that page when u click things). Search bars means nothing since it could either A/ lead to a hard coded page (which means we can get to the page without searching) or B/ it changes the information on the search page. If it's the prior one, ping the page with a head request (only getting headder info) and if it returns status 200 then scrap it normally. If it's the latter option you will need one of the two methods I mention above.

Comment: so can you simplify more... :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127264/discussion-between-nephilimrising-and-mooingrawr).